# How to get better at Wordament?

Tags: wordament

I started to play Wordament on my Windows phone and it seems like no matter how many games I play best rating I got was 35%. When I get 40 words best players get 140 words.

Is there tricks to this game that other people use or is it just better vocabulary? Is there a way to train?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly just practice. Everyone has to start somewhere and those pros that get over 100 words per game generally started in the same place as you. Most of them have also been playing for years. Really, it takes time, but you'll likely see you self gradually improve. When I first started I was happy to get over 15% and ecstatic to get over 30%. Now, a bunch of months later, I probably average about 90%. Not quite genius level, but a definite improvement. It also helps to study the words that you missed and tap them to see how they could have been selected on the screen. This should make you more likely to find them in the future. Hope this helps!